# how to divide a column of a matrix to a constant number in numpy?

Tags: python, numpy

I try this division and get these strange zeros instead of correct numbers.

```
i = 0
data_x = np.array([[3104, 5, 1, 45], [1416, 3, 2, 40], [852, 2, 1, 35]])
mu_i = np.mean(data_x[:,i])
print(mu_i)
max_num = np.max(data_x[:,i])
min_num = np.min(data_x[:,i])
d = (max_num - min_num)
print(d)
data_x[:,i] = (data_x[:,i] - mu_i)/d

data_x
```

result:

```
1790.6666666666667
0,5,1,45
0,3,2,40
0,2,1,35
```

Comment: can u say ur expected value ? are u trying to do something on axis=1 for example ?

Comment: You need to define `array` with `dtype = float`. Try this: `data_x = np.array([[3104, 5, 1, 45], [1416, 3, 2, 40], [852, 2, 1, 35]], dtype='float')`

Comment: @I'mahdi
 why did they set the default value to int!? it is really strange

Comment: Because you initialized the array with `int`s. `123` is an `int`. `123.0` or `123.` is a `float`. Why wouldn't numpy use the same data type you gave it?